# Check for a failed copy with scp

Tags: shell-script, scp

Is it possible in my code to verify if the file is well copied or not ?

```
ssh -t root@$machine -x "sshpass -p 'ubuntu' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  /home/MyFile.txt root@$address:~ "

ssh -t root@$machine -x "sshpass -p 'ubuntu' ssh -t root@$address -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -x 'cp MyFile.txt /etc/xx/MyFile.txt'"
```

Comment: I suppose something along the lines of using a command that gives a hash of the file.   Checkin that the source file has the same hash as the dest file.. maybe copying the hash of the source file over to the dest server and compare on the dest server. Not sure off hand what command and teh details though

Comment: Run sha{256,512}sum -c ~/path/to/file and then remotely  and cross check is one way,mm if  large files or numerous you could use md5sum too

Comment: Could you use rsync? It may be a better tool for this. It does verification automatically.